# How to initialize data for a function that is repeatedly called

Tags: python

This is surely a beginner's question, I'm just having trouble searching for it.

What I want to do is calculate points on a circle for thousands of circles which I will later render. Because I will be rendering many thousands of circles a second, I thought I'd try to avoid unncessary overhead. To do this, I've created a function that calculates a number of points (which I want to be variable, a larger circle will need more points calculated) on a unit circle, and another function which can take these points, translate them and then scale by the radius.

My original code ended up something like this:

```
class Circle():
...
def CalcCircle(segments):
    does some stuff to calculate generic coordinates

def CreateCircle(x, y, r, segments):        
    does some stuff to create a circle using CalcCircle(segments)
```

Obviously the problem was that even though I might only want to create circles with 20 segments, I was calling the CalcCircle function (and repeating the same calculations) every time I called CreateCircle.

The only way I could figure out how to fix this was:

```
class Circle():
...
def CalcCircle(segments):
    does some stuff to calculate generic coordinates

CreateCircle_has_not_been_run = True

def CreateCircle(x, y, r, segments):

    if Circle.TransCircle_has_not_been_run:
        generic_circle = Circle.CalcCircle(segments)
        Circle.CreateCircle_has_not_been_run = False

    does some stuff to create a circle using generic_circle
```

I've never formally learnt programming so I'm not sure if this is considered good design. Surely it would become messy if every time I wanted to "initialize" data or call a function only on the first run through I had to make a random class variable. The reason I ask is I'm constantly running into this problem, so I assume there must be a standard way of doing it.

Edit: An example of how the call will be made.

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    width = window.get_size()[0]
    height = window.get_size()[1]
    radius = int(width/50)
    segments = int(radius*1.5)
    for i in range(N):
        pyglet.gl.glColor3f(0.05,0.2,0.9)
        DrawCircle(positions[i][0],positions[i][1],width,segments)
    DrawCage(width,height)
    DrawLabel(width,height)
    etc.
```

I'm aware that there's problems here but I'm just trying to illustrate the example (positions comes from the update function if anyone is wondering). As I've said earlier, this is a problem I run into all the time.

I could call Circle.CalcCircle() from the on_resize() function as per Achim's suggestion. I have a hard time believing however that standard practice is to stick two random functions into a class (as it stands neither of them necessarily need to even be in the Circle class), one of which is implicitly dependent on the other and both of which are called in different parts of the code.

Comment: Why do you don't call `CalcCircle`, store the result and pass that into `CreateCircle`?

Comment: In this case, because CreateCircle is being called from an on_draw function which is rendering every 16 milliseconds or whatever. Incidentally I've had exactly the same problem with passing a 1,000 key dictionary in on_draw. I want to only modify the values (and I'm not sure how it works with memory if I'm reinitializing a 1000 key dictionary every 16 ms), in the end I used a global which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: More generally though, is it standard practice to have one function to initialize data and another to modify it? I'm trying to break free from the mindset of having global state and simply modifying it. It somewhat irks me having functions which modify data further up the hierarchy if that makes any sense. Or am I misunderstanding what constitutes good design?

Comment: I think I get an idea what your problem is, but it's hard to answer the question in a general way without having more context. Obviously you pass in segments, so it should also possible to pass in generic_circle. If not, the reason must be your calling code. Can you show a minimal example how segments is calculated and how your on_draw looks like? I would assume that your problem can be solved with a simple closure. ;-)

Comment: I think you're right, segments was determined by window size and I can just call CalcCircle whenever it is resized, rather than every draw call. Nonetheless I still don't like having to remember to create the generic circle data in one place then having to call upon it in a totally different place. David's solution feels more explicit...

Comment: I consider the side effects in David's solution very bad OO programming. But if you don't tell more details about your real use case, I cannot propose a better solution.

Comment: What are the negative side effects? Also, another solution I'm toying with is to stick all the CalcCircle code into __init__, so a circle with 20 sides is an instance which can later be translated/dilated with a method.

Comment: Just memoize your calls?  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.unit_circle_points = None

    def CalcCircle(self, segments):
        # Do some stuff to calculate segments, 
        # assign calculated values to class attribute
        self.unit_circle_points = calculated_points

    def CreateCircle(self, X, y, r, segments):
        # If circle points have not yet been calculated then calculate
        # and store, else just load stored points
        if self.unit_circle_points is None:
            self.CalcCircle(segments)
        unit_circle_points = self.unit_circle_points

        # Now use unit_circle_points to do some calculations
```

Every time you instantiate a circle object it will come with an attribute named `unit_circle_points` that is initialized to `None`. When you call the `CreateCircle` method on that object for the first time it will see that the `unit_circle_points` attribute is `None` and perform the necessary computations by calling `CalcCircle`, storing the results. On subsequent calls to the `CreateCircle` method of this `Circle` object the `unit_circle_points` attribute will no longer be `None`, and the method will simply use the values stored in the attribute.

Edit:

If this requires to much "implicit" behavior for your taste, you can shift things around so that CalcCircle must be called explicitly by the user to generate the pre-calculated data.

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.unit_circle_points = None

    def CalcCircle(self, segments):
        # Do some stuff to calculate segments, 
        # assign calculated values to class attribute
        self.unit_circle_points = calculated_points
        return self

    def CreateCircle(self, X, y, r):
        # If circle points have not yet been calculated then raise an error,
        # else load previously calculated points
        if self.unit_circle_points is None:
            raise Exception("You'd better explicitly call CalcCircle first.")
        unit_circle_points = self.unit_circle_points

        # Now use unit_circle_points to do some calculations
```

Comment: I think this is what I'll do, it's much cleaner than what I had and  having a method act on the instance seems much more explicit than having one class function call on the data from another class function, especially when it might be a big class and you're calling them both at very different places in your code.
 I'm still getting my head around OOP.

Comment: I consider this kind of implicit side effects as very bad OO programming.

Comment: Wow harsh, seems to me that this provides the exact functionality the OP was looking for. Check out the revised version.

Comment: Just a sidenote that functionality isn't really my problem, my original code works fine. I'm just curious as to what is considered the best way of doing it, seeing as I have no real way of developing good programming practices by simply making up my own projects.

Comment: Gotcha, my original intent was to provide a cleaner version of your implementation. The second option I've added is a little bit different, but in some sense probably safer.

Comment: Your new version is not "a little bit" different. It's already much better, but still you have a class where you cannot call CreateCircle without calling CalcCircle. Try to write documentation for that. It might somehow work for this single property, but add a second one and you will fall into chaos. If you have to call CalcCircle anyhow, why not do it in __init__? All this strange workarounds to call the code are based on the external requirements the OP does not tell us about. So I'm very sorry, but I cannot propose something better. But this is - in my opinion - still bad OOP.

Comment: Calling `CalcCircle` from `__init__` with a `segments` argument is certainly an option. Of course then if you have a secondary purpose for `segments` you will be locked in to performing a possibly unnecessary function call. I agree that it's not ideal to have `CreateCircle` depend on a prior call to `CalcCircle`, but failure to follow the correct sequence is immediate and obvious. The other option you suggest of passing in a separately calculated `generic_circle` object separates data and functionality that in my opinion logically belong together. This is a simple solution to a simple problem.

Comment: In any case I have redone my code so that CalcCircle is within the init, which is probably the best solution. I still don't think Achim's solution was any better than David's, I would have had the CalcCircle call in on_resize, the CreateCircle call in on_draw and the data stored as a global?

Comment: Sounds like a good solution to me. Just make sure that you're calling CalcCircle from within __init__, not actually sticking the CalcCircle code in __init__. (By the way, I don't think Achim was suggesting you use globals, just that you pass some pre-initialized data as an argument to on_draw() and on_resize()).